# How to compare strings in python 2 and 3?

Tags: python

I was playing around with some python and came up with this code:

```
import time
N = 10000000
t1 = time.time()
for _ in range(N):
    if 'lol' in ['lol']:
        pass
print(time.time() - t1)

t1 = time.time()
for _ in range(N):
    if 'lol' == 'lol':
        pass
print(time.time() - t1)
```

so, if I use `python2`:

```
(test) C:\Users\test>python test.py
0.530999898911
0.5

(test) C:\Users\test>python test.py
0.531000137329
0.5

(test) C:\Users\test>python test.py
0.528000116348
0.501000165939
```

And it is nice - I like that second variant is quicker and I should use `'lol' == 'lol'` as it is more pythonic way to compare two strings.
But what happens if I use `python3`:

```
(test) C:\Users\test>python3 test.py
0.37500524520874023
0.3880295753479004

(test) C:\Users\test>python3 test.py
0.3690001964569092
0.3780345916748047

(test) C:\User\test>python3 test.py
0.37799692153930664
0.38797974586486816
```

using timeit:

```
(test) C:\Users\test>python3 -m timeit "'lol' in ['lol']"
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0183 usec per loop

(test) C:\Users\test>python3 -m timeit "'lol' == 'lol'"
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.019 usec per loop
```

O my god! Why first variant is quicker? So should I use ugly style like `'lol' in ['lol']` when i use `python3`?

Comment: Show your timings with the `timeit` module

Comment: You can run these quickly on the command line with `python3 -m timeit "'lol' == 'lol'"`

Comment: You're talking about fractions of a second here.  If your application is that performance critical you probably shouldn't be using python in the first place.  Focus on making your code easy to understand.

Comment: The answer to your question is absolutely NO. You should code in a readable way and optimize if you need to.

Comment: _"So should I use ugly style like `'lol' in ['lol']` when i use python3?"_ - No, no, no, no, no, no. As others have already said, you primary goal should be making readable code. Only optimize when you _have_ to. Remember, code is written once but read many times. Also, I have doubts if using `in` is _truly_ faster.

Comment: If you want my educated guess at *why* the first variant is very slightly quicker, see my comments under Josh's answer

Comment: This is a completely valid question, highlighting some of python's more confusing behavior. There is no need to question the motivations behind it so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So should I use ugly style like 'lol' in ['lol'] when i use python3?

No, [readability counts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Also, as others have noted, your test case has weaknesses:

```
$ python3 -m timeit "'lol' == 'lol'"
>> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.024 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit "'lol' in ['lol']"
>> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0214 usec per loop
$ python2 -m timeit "'lol' == 'lol'"
>> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0258 usec per loop
$ python2 -m timeit "'lol' in ['lol']"
>> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0212 usec per loop
```

There is no difference between python2 and python3 when it comes to which comparison is faster.

---

Another source of confusion might be due to the opaque behavior of python interpreters[1] when it comes to string caching/interning. As a rule of thumb, strings shorter than four characters are interned and will refer to the same object. It can be tested with something like

```
a = 'lol'
b = 'lol'
a is b  # tests for object id instead of applying an equality comparison
>> True
```

Other strings may also be interned, but an easy counterexample is one of a string with 4 characters that includes special characters:

```
a = '####'
b = '####'
a is b
>> False
```

Of course, testing for object ids is faster than making an actual comparison, and your test using `in` did just that. Even though the code itself looks straight forward, the actual operation was unexpected. That also means that slightly different scenarios may lead to surprising results and Funny Bugs.

In conclusion I'd repeat once more: No, you should not prefer the second variant of comparison over the first.

[1]: [Only CPython](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/codeobject.c#l49). I do not know if other python interpreters do something similar.

Comment: It feels like you took this edit idea directly from my comments. Anyway, you've explained it wrong, there is no `is in` example. The `in` operator for lists tests first identity and second (if the first fails) equality, hence why it can be very marginally faster as I explained under Josh's answer

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks for spotting the typo. I wanted to address interning from the start, but since it is not what OP asked about I added it as an afterthought, and not in the main answer,

Answer (score 4):

The bulk of your python2 time is in constructing a huge list by calling `range`. Change it to `xrange` in Python 2, or use the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module which is properly written. Once you've done that, you will not find an appreciable difference that will motivate writing strange-looking code.

Comment: Out of interest, do you have any insights on *why* the `in` operator is (fractionally) faster than an equality check?

Comment: @ACascarino I think the reason is that the `in` operator tests not only equality `==` but also identity `is` and `python3 -m timeit "'lol' is 'lol'"` is fastest. However, of course `is` is not required to give the correct result for more complex strings (depends on string interning), so it's not recommended for these purposes

Comment: @ACascarino Some evidence: `'lol' is ''.join('lol')` >> `False`, `python3 -m timeit "'lol' == ''.join('lol')"` >> `0.244` and `python3 -m timeit "'lol' in [''.join('lol')]"` >> `0.277`. So the negligible time advantage of `in` is reversed when 2 strings being compared are not identical

Comment: There's an even finer distinction if the unidentical strings have the same length or a different length.